# Добрый вечер. Помогите пожалуйста чут-чуть алгоритм доработать

Tags: python, олимпиада, динамическое-программирование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: ****]

Добрый вечер. Задача очень простая, но наверное есть какой-то крайний случай и поэтому у меня WA на 3 тесте. Тот 3 тест который представлен в условии, у меня правильный ответ выдаёт

Comment: Вставьте код и текст задания текстом вместо скриншотов.

Answer (score 1):

То, что вы считаете - количество сочетаний `C(n+k-1,k)`, оно же количество путей на решетке `k x (n-1)` из угла в угол.

Однако, похоже, что вы не в полной мере учитываете "физический смысл" - в данном случае правила игры.

Частично учитываете - т.к. использование `n-1` как раз говорит о том, что последний шаг всегда делается вправо.

Но если одна из команд набрала M очков, а вторая M-2, то игра закончена, т.е. часть путей, которые упираются в вертикали M > 25 - не валидные, их нельзя учитывать.